# Nested calls in Python - do I need try except inside all the functions?

Tags: python, python-3.6, try-except

I am in process of learning python try:except clause

I have the following call hierarchy

```
def A():
     try:
         B(some_args)
     except Exception as e:
         print (repr(e))
```

B is implemented as following

```
def B(some_args):
    C(some_args)
```

Note that there is no try except inside B
I have a try except inside C as following

```
def C():
     try:
         dothis()
     except exception as e:
         raise e
```

My question is that if one of the functions in the call hierarchy(B in this case)

```
A()
    calls B()
        calls C()
```

doesn't have a try except clause, would A still receive the exception raised in C()?

Comment: Yes, in other words you don't need try-except inside intermediate functions like B in your example. That being said, it is often wise to design it such that more general exceptions are handled at a higher level (ie A does not need to be bothered with specificities of G or H).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would.  A try/catch block will catch any exception thrown inside the try block, regardless of how deep the place is where it is thrown.

Also, you can **catch** specific exceptions at various levels, so it can be the case that a catch block in B might catch one thrown exception, whereas the catch block in A will catch a different exception, each possibly thrown in C or even some other function that C calls, etc.  For example:

```
catch FileNotFoundException as ex:
```

would catch a FileNotFoundException, but not other exceptions